# Property value in xaml not picked up

Tags: xaml, properties

I declare my custom control in xaml as follow:

```
<local:CustomControl Visiblity="Hidden"/>
```

and override CustomControl.OnApplyTemplate()

```
OnApplyTemplate():
{
   base.OnApplyTemplate();
   var show = Visibility == Visibility.Visible; // always true!!!
}
```

Why is the value of the Visibility property is still Visible? When will the value be applied?